# RSA Cipher, how to secure save public and private keys?

Tags: python, cryptography

I want to encypt my sql database file using RSA cipher. So, i have two keys public and private, and they just stand "naked" in the code like:

```
...
privKey = "salosalsolaosloals23232"
pubKey = "olsolsosloslsosls123123"
...
```

So, the question is, how to hide them, and make code more secure?
I have tried to keep them in separated txt files, but it`s not that, that i want, because you still able to read/see them, is there any methods to hide them at all?

Comment: you might have an XY problem...

Comment: But why? :D
All i want to know, is how to secure hide keys  @Mitch Wheat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every strategy you'll consider will still have the problem where if you yourself have access to that secret, anyone with the same level of access will have it as well.  You can never fully secure a system, you can just make it harder for someone to break in.  If you make it harder to break in than the profit of breaking in, people won't want to go through the trouble, and you can probably keep things safe.

To solve this kind of a problem, you have to frame it based on from whom you are trying to protect a secret.  You are correct that leaving the secret (the private half of your keys) in your code means that anyone who can see your code can see the encryption key.  However, is this reasonable for your threat model?  Is it easy for someone else to gain access to your file system? Or would it be easier for someone to get access to your database backups instead?

If they have access to your filesystem, does that mean they also have root on the machine? Your options for protecting against someone who has full access and control of the machine hosting your application are pretty limited!  If they can attach debugging tools to the process they may even be able to read your secret from memory anyway.

Here's a series of escalating levels of protection:

1. (not at all secure) Keep your secret in code. As long  as nobody can see your code (such as in a public Github repo), then they can't see your secret.
2. (little better) Keep your secret in a file that only lives in production. Now if the attacker has access to an offline backup of your data, they cannot read the contents without that additional file.
3. (pretty good) Type your secret in on deploy.  This now protects against if the attacker is able to download the contents of your production filesystem.  You can either type in the literal secret, or keep a file containing your key encrypted with an easier-to-remember encryption secret that you type in on deploy.
4. (extra paranoid) Use a service that generates the encryption keys for you, and use a deployment platform that integrates with it.  This is a pretty extensive industry with many competing products, and I do not want to endorse any particular one.  You have your vendor generate the encryption keys for you, and your deployment vendor coordinate with it to inject those secrets on deploy.  This protects against if an attacker has installed a keylogger on your laptop, where typing in the secret on deploy would leak the secret.